# TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 9, file "Code")

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, typeerror

I am using the below filter function to copy data from one sheet to another, filtering out so that it only copies data if column AE = TRUE.
When I use this script, it gives me the error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 9, file "Code")'

I am not sure what the getRange section means.

```
function myFunction() {
var sss = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById('1V3Tl4h43AC92K4gQtvdZ07k01QJOnfwSD1BKKTziHJU'); 
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('<20 Filter'); 
var range = ss.getRange('A:AE'); 
var data = range.getValues();

var tss = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById('1AKL81cN5QWTWSsSfuMGcFRED5QpeAK022k8VwrPl7sA'); 
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Zones >20 Riders'); 
ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, 
data[0].length).setValues(data);

var range = ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, 
data[0].length)
var rawData = range.getValues()     // get value from spreadsheet 2
var data = []                       // Filtered Data will be stored in this array
for (var i = 0; i< rawData.length ; i++){
if(rawData[i][30] == "TRUE")            
{
data.push(rawData[i])
}
}
}
```

Or could I use this script?

```
function myFunction() {
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1V3Tl4h43AC92K4gQtvdZ07k01QJOnfwSD1BKKTziHJU'); //replace with source ID
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('<20 Filter'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
var range = ss.getRange('A:AE');      //assign the range you want to copy
var rawData = range.getValues()     // get value from spreadsheet 1
var data = []                       // Filtered Data will be stored in this array
for (var i = 0; i< rawData.length ; i++){
if(rawData[i][30] == "TRUE")           
{
data.push(rawData[i])
}
}
var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1AKL81cN5QWTWSsSfuMGcFRED5QpeAK022k8VwrPl7sA'); //replace with destination ID
var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Zones <20 Riders'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

}
```

But it gives me the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 15, file "Code")

Answer (score 1):

It means that `tss.getSheetByName('Zones >20 Riders');` did not return anything. You need to check that indeed a sheet was found before trying to access it.

Here's the example provided at [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String)):

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Expenses");

if (sheet != null) {
    // Do your thing
}
```

---

If you are not sure what a method does, always check the documentation. For example, [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRange(String)) returns the specified [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) of cells in the sheet.

Answer (score -1):

try changing as below

```
var sss = 
SpreadsheetApp.openById('1V3Tl4h43AC92K4gQtvdZ07k01QJOnfwSD1BKKTziHJU'); 
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('<20 Filter'); 
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange('A:AE'); 
var data = range.getValues();
```

note: `getSheets` returns the sheet this range belongs to.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unforuntately this didn't work. Could I try using this script?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot find function getSheets in object Sheet. (line 5, file "Code")

Comment: can you console.log(ss) after var ss = sss.getSheetByName('<20 Filter');

Comment: That still gives me the same error if I put
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('<20 Filter'); console.log(ss) or 
var ss = sss.getSheetByName('<20 Filter'); 
console.log(ss)

Comment: nope, cant be. since your trying to console log "var ss = sss.getSheetByName('<20 Filter'); console.log(ss)" even before your calling the getSheets. then something should have printed, null or something mate.

Comment: Yeah it still just gives me this error :( 
TypeError: Cannot find function getSheets in object Sheet. (line 5, file "Code")

Comment: Any other suggestions on a filter script? How about the other one I posted 'Could I use this script?...'?